# What's the best way to auto hide a custom bufferline when there is only one buffer listed?

Tags: neovim, buffers, autocmd

this is gonna be a lengthy question.

I'm developing a neovim bufferline plugin which shows a list of all the buffers in the tabline. I'm trying to implement a auto-hide feature, where the bufferline is only shown if there are two or more buffers open.

To do this, I'm currently listening to the `BufAdd` and `BufUnload` autocmds. This is what I'm using now

```
autocmd VimEnter,BufAdd * call myplugin#toggle(expand('<afile>'), 1)
autocmd BufUnload * call myplugin#toggle(expand('<afile>'), 2)
```

where the `myplugin#toggle` autoloaded function is

```
function! myplugin#toggle(filename, threshold)
  if !buflisted(a:filename) | return | endif
  let l:buffers = getbufinfo({'buflisted': 1})
  execute 'set showtabline=' . (len(l:buffers) > a:threshold ? '2' : '0')
endfunction
```

the first line is used as a guard against unwanted events. For example, if I have two opened buffers and open the help page (`:h`), when I close it the toggle function gets called and the bufferline gets hidden, which I don't want.

However this is not a perfect solution. For example if I have a single buffer, opening the help page causes the bufferline to show, even after the help page is closed.

I've tried way too many different combinations of autocmd events (`BufUnload` vs `BufDelete`), parameters (`<afile>` vs `<abuf>` vs `%`) and conditions (`buflisted`, `bufloaded`, `nvim_buf_is_valid`, etc.), but none of them seem to work.

I'm drowning in autocmd hell. Can somebody help?

Comment: Does it work if you use a single event of BufEnter and the threshold of 1? After you close a buffer, you'll enter another one, then you can reevaluate whether to show or hide the bufferline again...

Comment: Yes but that'd be wasteful. I'd like to evaluate that function only when I need to.

Comment: PS `let &showtabline = len(buffers) > a:threshold ? 2 : 0`, no execute necessary